# Numpy loadtxt single line into multidim-array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have a textfile, `randomfile.txt`, containing a lot of values separated with blankstep, basically one single long line of different numbers.

```
10 20 30 40 50 10 45 65.......
```

I'm using `numpy.loadtxt` to read all the values into python. What I want to do next is divide the long line of numbers into a 2-dimensional numpy array with four columns.

I want the array structure to be the following:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[50, 10, 45, 65]
```

I have tried to use `numpy.reshape` to modify the array, but the problem is that the values are read-in as a single line of code.

I'd be thankful for suggestions on how to solve this, or tips of tutorials I could dig myself into.

Comment: That is not a 4-dimensional array. It looks like a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "2-dimensional numpy array with four columns." If I've made a mistake, sorry! In that case, please edit your question to clarify. Also -- to get correct code formatting, you can select your code block and press the `{}` button at the top of the edit window.

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line :

```
np.loadtxt("randomfile.txt", dtype=int).reshape((-1, 4))
```

gets me the following output :

```
array([[10, 20, 30, 40],
       [50, 10, 45, 65]])
```

with your sample data.

Comment: Wierd, that is basicly what i tried without success. Now it works! thanks!